# How to use ActivityIndicator in an async method

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created an ActivityIndicator

```
<AbsoluteLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Grid.Row="1">
    <ActivityIndicator 
       x:Name="activity"  
       IsRunning="False"  
       IsEnabled="False"  
       IsVisible="False"  
       Color="#49c7AB"  
       BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and I have a button which has the following click void

```
async void IbtnEnglisch_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activity.IsEnabled = true;
    activity.IsRunning = true;
    activity.IsVisible = true;

    //do some stuff
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Auswahl());

    activity.IsEnabled = false;
    activity.IsRunning = false;
    activity.IsVisible = false;
}
```

The ActivityIndicator is not shown during my stuff gets loaded. But when I get back to my side, than I can see it (of course when it is not set to false at the end).

I have tried to do something like this:

```
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
      {
           //do my stuff
           await Navigation.PushAsync(new Auswahl());
      });
```

But it is also not working.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try a trigger? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers

Comment: I am also confused as to what youre trying to do, as soon as its set to true, youre pushing a new view on top that will hide the activity indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From shared code , that will not work . Because all code will be called at the same time inside `IbtnEnglisch_Clicked` `Button` click method .

```
async void IbtnEnglisch_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activity.IsEnabled = true;
    activity.IsRunning = true;
    activity.IsVisible = true;

    //do some stuff
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Auswahl());

    activity.IsEnabled = false;
    activity.IsRunning = false;
    activity.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Have a try with `Timer` to deal with that , then it will work . When task be finished , it will navigate to next page and hide the `ActivityIndicator` .

Sample code :

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    activity.IsEnabled = true;
    activity.IsRunning = true;
    activity.IsVisible = true;


    // await method here do task method 
    // here monitor a taskCount to know whether task be finished
    int taskCount = 0;
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
    {
        // called every 1 second
        // do stuff here
        taskCount++;
        if (taskCount == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finish");
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage() { Title = "new page" });
            activity.IsEnabled = false;
            activity.IsRunning = false;
            activity.IsVisible = false;
            return false; // return true to repeat counting, false to stop timer
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working for me perfekt.

Comment: I started a project to solve this problem. I created a NUGET too.

https://github.com/plucenio/Plugin.XamExecuteAndWait

You are welcome to help me.